# Reading .Rds file in python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm currently trying to read a rds file using rpy2 package.
Here is my code

```
import rpy2.robjects as objects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('sampleb.rds')
```

I'm getting the following error

```
From cffi callback <function _consolewrite_ex at 0x0000023D3B601CA0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\callbacks.py", line 132, in _consolewrite_ex
    s = conversion._cchar_to_str_with_maxlen(buf, n, _CCHAR_ENCODING)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\conversion.py", line 133, in _cchar_to_str_with_maxlen
    s = ffi.string(c, maxlen).decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 85677: invalid start 
byte
[1]
attr(,"class")
[1] "json"
```

Comment: What happens when you read file with `readRDS` directly inside R?

Comment: Thanks you. There were some issues with the RDS file itself. I figured it out by trying to open in using R!